# Could the inequality $0<x(1-y^{-\frac{1}{x}})<2$ be solved?

Tags: inequality

Could the inequality $0<x(1-y^{-\frac{1}{x}})<2,x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+$ be solved? I have tried a various of ways but seems impossible to solve. Is there a way to solve this inequality, or a way to proof there does not exist solution?

I need to find out the $x$ and $y$ such that the inequality satisfy.

Thanks very much~

Comment: This is not an inequality. Where is the $\geq$ or $\leq$ sign? And what is the other side of the expression?

Comment: And do you want to solve for $x$ of $y$?

Comment: $x=1, \quad y=2$

Comment: $x=$ whatever, $y=1$ leads to zero and the left inequality is not satisfied. Did you miss typing the possibility of equalities ?

Comment: What do you mean by **solve**? My solution $x=1,\;y=2$ still stands after you edit the question (both are strictly positive).

Comment: Thanks @gammatester - I am trying to find all the solution.

Comment: @gammatester You're right solve isn't clear. But it might be along the lines of if you were asked to solve $y<x$ you would say it's the area under the line $y=x$.

Comment: A partial result: From $0<x(1-y^{-\frac{1}{x}})$ you get $1>y^{-\frac{1}{x}}=1/y^{\frac{1}{x}}$ or
$y^{\frac{1}{x}}>1$, and therefore $y>1.$

Comment: Maybe taking logs might help.

Comment: Another partial result $y=\left(\frac{x}{x-a}\right)^x$ is the line which upperbounds the expression to $a$.

Comment: @gammatester, building on your constraint $y>1$, and example $(1,2)$ an obvious set of points that satisfy the inequality is $\{(x,y)\}$ such that $x\le2,y>1$.

Comment: @TooTone, I guess for $y\le e^2$ all $x>0$ are solutions, and for $y > e^2$ the value for $x$ with $x(1-y^{-\frac{1}{x}})=2$ could most probably expressed with the LambertW function (but Maple refuses to give a result for variable $y$)

Comment: @gammatester Cool, I [plotted the values numerically](http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2427-126.html) and could see $y$ tending to a value around $7\approx e^2$ as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One have to separate in the study if three cases :

[image]

The previous "sketch of the ranges of validity (green)" was not fully satisfising. It is remplaced by a more precise drawing. Thanks to some comments, the limit of $y$ when $x$ tends to infinity is $e²$, which is confirmed by asymptotic expansion.

Comment: That's excellent! Thank you so much!!